# Spark row_number partitionBy without order by to keep natural order

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'd like to realize partition without any order by, so that data can keep it's natural sorting in the data frame. Please share any advice, thanks in advance.

Consider there are following data in a Spark data frame

```
         raw data
----------------------------
 name | item id |   action
----------------------------
 John |    120  |   sell 
----------------------------
 John |    320  |   buy
----------------------------
 Jane |    120  |   sell 
----------------------------
 Jane |    450  |   buy
----------------------------
 Sam  |    360  |   sell 
----------------------------
 Sam  |    300  |   hold
----------------------------
 Sam  |    450  |   buy
----------------------------
 Tim  |    470  |   buy
----------------------------
```

There is are couple rules in this table schema

```
1. Every one has at least one action `buy`
2. Every one's last action must be `buy` as well
```

Now I'd like to add a sequence column, just to show the order of action for everyone

```
            expectation
--------------------------------------
 name | item id |   action  |  seq   
--------------------------------------
 John |    120  |   sell    |  1
--------------------------------------
 John |    320  |   buy     |  2
--------------------------------------
 Jane |    120  |   sell    |  1
--------------------------------------
 Jane |    450  |   buy     |  2
--------------------------------------
 Sam  |    360  |   sell    |  1
--------------------------------------
 Sam  |    300  |   hold    |  2
--------------------------------------
 Sam  |    450  |   buy     |  3
--------------------------------------
 Tim  |    470  |   buy     |  1
--------------------------------------
```

so here is my code

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{row_number}
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
....

val df = spark.read.json(....)
val spec = Window.partitionBy($"name").orderBy(lit(1))         <-- don't know what to used for order by

val dfWithSeq = df.withColumn("seq", row_number.over(spec))   <--- please show me the magic
```

Interestingly, the result back from `dfWithSeq`, shows random sequence was given to actions under each person, so with the seq the action is no longer follow the order given in the original data table. However I couldn't find a solution.

```
           actual result
--------------------------------------
 name | item id |   action  |  seq   
--------------------------------------
 John |    120  |   sell    |  1
--------------------------------------
 John |    320  |   buy     |  2
--------------------------------------
 Jane |    120  |   sell    |  2          <-- this is wrong
--------------------------------------
 Jane |    450  |   buy     |  1          <-- this is wrong
--------------------------------------
 Sam  |    360  |   sell    |  1
--------------------------------------
 Sam  |    300  |   hold    |  2
--------------------------------------
 Sam  |    450  |   buy     |  3
--------------------------------------
 Tim  |    470  |   buy     |  1
--------------------------------------
```

Comment: How do you know the order of action? Is there any timestamp column or any other way to define the order ?

Comment: @koiralo thanks, What I tried to achieve is just to keep the original order of action without any changes, just basically, no order by at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to use:

- zipWithIndex after converting to RDD and back to DF. This is a narrow transformation that will preserve your (initial) data ordering.
- then do you partitionBy appropriately taking into account that sequence number within the name or what ever.

Leave you to work out the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `monotonically_increasing_id`.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{row_number, monotonically_increasing_id}
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
....

val df = spark.read.json(....)
val spec = Window.partitionBy($"name").orderBy($"order")

val dfWithSeq = df.withColumn("order", monotonically_increasing_id)
  .withColumn("seq", row_number.over(spec))
```